# HP laserjet 1022n problems on windows server 2003 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, printer, drivers

Our HP laserjet 1022n works fine on everything except whenever it is asked to print a document with some sizes of calibri type font, instead of printing normally, it spews out gibberish (things like &"*#$-#"-% instead of the word "maintenance") I assume this is because calibri is a Clear-Type font, however, since calibri is now the default font of Word and excel, this has become a large issue.

First I updated the drivers that were in place, which were HP's universal drivers; still the same problem. Next I decided to try the printer's own drivers - Big mistake, these drivers ended up crashing our print spool service. So now I am wondering if anyone using this same printer still has any methods of getting this printer to understand calibri under windows server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

When you print, go to File, Print, Properties. Pick "Advanced" tab, set "Send TrueType as bitmaps" Enabled. That usually fixes font problems

Comment: Nice, I'll remember that one!

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix I am running HP LaserJet 5Si drivers, substituting the Calibri font with Times New Roman, this works for now, but the text is slightly warped (spaces in between characters). I would still welcome any other work-arounds or solutions to this.